# CFSE for octahedral complexes with more than one type of ligands

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

How would be crystal field stabilization energy for the complex [Co(NH3)5Cl]²-? I guess that due to the presence of negative ligand Cl-  3 sets of d orbitals can be present with a dz²or dx²-y²orbital of a slightly little different energy.

Comment: Do $\ce{Cl}$ electrons interact with $\ce{e_g}$ or $\ce{t_{2g}}$ set of orbitals?

Comment: I do want to know too

Answer (score -2):

When more than one type of ligands are present with some being SFL and others being WFL then, the final effect of those ligands dominate which are greater in number. So, in the given compound, ammonia is more than chlorine so effect of SFL dominates and you get inner orbital complex

Comment: I wonder .. how this answer is connected to the question.

Comment: Then what do you want to know, please clarify

Comment: How the d orbitals are split - their energy level diagram under the influence of both the ligands!